# Android Picasso image load issue

Tags: android

I use Picasso library for manage my listview's images. Although images download, they don't appear in imageview immediately. When i scroll page, they appear spontaneously. Relative code snippet:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(objects.get(position).getUrl()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ins).error(R.mipmap.aramam).into(new Target() {
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            Bitmap d = getCircleBitmap(bitmap);
            holder.image1.setImageBitmap(d);
        }

        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            holder.image1.setImageBitmap(getCircleBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.bos_prof)));
        }
    });
```

Additional info : When i re-download listview objects , they appear spontaneously too.

Why is this happening??

Comment: what you mean by *they appear spontaneously.*? How would you expect them to appear ?

Comment: When i scroll down on list , they appear instantly. Or when i click listview item (image was sending with intent to another activity), image can seen in another activity. I expect that when images download , they appear in listview.

Comment: I think it has something to do with placeholders... I have faced this problem too.... the images don't appear until you scroll the listview (may be because scrolling refreshes list items). Idk why this happens. Can you check it without using placeholders?

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work. Yes when i pull my swipe refresh, images appear instantly too.

Answer (score 0):

In picasso problem with Target , with Target they have some issue which you can find [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues).